# Calculator Microsoft visual studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, calculator

i have put this code to stop insert two operators , is working on +, *, / but 
not working on "-" , when tried to put (-3-3)   you have to press the equal button to allowed another operator to be insert

```
Public Class Form1

    'Global variable to check if equals has been pressed
    Dim is_equals_pressed As Boolean = False

    Dim operator_count As Integer = 0
    Dim allowed_input As Boolean = False


Private Sub btnMinus_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMinus.Click
        operator_count += 1

        allowed_input = Check_Values()
        If allowed_input <> False Then

            If txtAnswer.Text = "" Then

                If Check_Values() = False Then
                    txtAnswer.Focus()
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If

            If is_equals_pressed = True Then
                txtTyped.Text = txtAnswer.Text & "-"
                txtAnswer.Text = ""    'clear the text box
                is_equals_pressed = False

            Else

                txtTyped.Text += txtAnswer.Text & "-"
                txtAnswer.Text = ""    'clear the text box
                txtAnswer.Focus()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnMultiply_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMultiply.Click
        operator_count += 1

        allowed_input = Check_Values()
        If allowed_input <> False Then

            If txtAnswer.Text = "" Then

                If Check_Values() = False Then
                    txtAnswer.Focus()
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If

            If is_equals_pressed = True Then
                txtTyped.Text = txtAnswer.Text & "*"
                txtAnswer.Text = ""    'clear the text box
                is_equals_pressed = False

            Else

                txtTyped.Text += txtAnswer.Text & "*"
                txtAnswer.Text = ""    'clear the text box
                txtAnswer.Focus()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

Private Sub btnEquals_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEquals.Click
        Dim equation As String


        operator_count = 0

        'Cos, Sin, Tan
        Dim num1 As String
        'End

        Dim i As Integer = 1

        txtTyped.Text += txtAnswer.Text
        'Capture value for Cos, Sin, Tan calculation
        num1 = txtAnswer.Text
        'End

        txtAnswer.Text = ("") 'Clear the text box

        equation = txtTyped.Text

        'Check if equals has been pressed
        is_equals_pressed = True

        'Check for +, -, =, / simbol in string
        For i = 1 To equation.Length - 1
            If equation(i) = "+" Then
                addNumbers(equation)
            ElseIf equation(i) = "-" Then
                subtrtactNumbers(equation)
            ElseIf equation(i) = "*" Then
                multiplyNumbers(equation)
            ElseIf equation(i) = "/" Then
                divideNumbers(equation)
            ElseIf equation(i) = "^" Then
                exponentNumber(equation)
            ElseIf equation(i) = "%" Then
                modulusNumbers(equation)
            ElseIf equation.Contains("1/") Then
                inverseNumbers(equation)

                'We do this calculation in btnCos_Click
            ElseIf equation.Contains("Cos") Then
            ElseIf equation.Contains("Sin") Then
            ElseIf equation.Contains("Tan") Then

            End If
        Next

        txtAnswer.Select(txtAnswer.Text.Length, 0)

    End Sub

 Private Function Check_Values() As Boolean



        If operator_count > 1 Then
            allowed_input = False
        Else
            allowed_input = True
        End If

        Check_Values = allowed_input

    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

(-3-3) Here you already have two "-" operators, because the first minus is also treated as an operator, so the Check_Values() returns False. To fix that, in btnMinus_Click you can check if the minus is NOT the first character and only in that case inrecase the operator_count.

Comment: can you type the code for that please to make more sense Thanks for the reply

Comment: I think it should be enough to add `If txtTyped.Text == "" Then Return` at the very beginning of `btnMinus_Click`